# TypeError: fit() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given) with sklearn and sklearn_pandas

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, kaggle

I'm trying to use the sklearn_pandas module to extend the work I do in pandas and dip a toe into machine learning but I'm struggling with an error I don't really understand how to fix.

I was working through the following dataset on [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/c/data-science-london-scikit-learn/data).

It's essentially an unheadered table (1000 rows, 40 features) with floating point values.

```
import pandas as pdfrom sklearn import neighbors
from sklearn_pandas import DataFrameMapper, cross_val_score
path_train ="../kaggle/scikitlearn/train.csv"
path_labels ="../kaggle/scikitlearn/trainLabels.csv"
path_test = "../kaggle/scikitlearn/test.csv"

train = pd.read_csv(path_train, header=None)
labels = pd.read_csv(path_labels, header=None)
test = pd.read_csv(path_test, header=None)
mapper_train = DataFrameMapper([(list(train.columns),neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3))])
mapper_train
```

Output:

```
DataFrameMapper(features=[([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39], KNeighborsClassifier(algorithm='auto', leaf_size=30, metric='minkowski',
       n_neighbors=3, p=2, weights='uniform'))])
```

So far so good. But then I try the fit

```
mapper_train.fit_transform(train, labels)
```

Output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-e3897d6db1b5> in <module>()
----> 1 mapper_train.fit_transform(train, labels)

//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/base.pyc in fit_transform(self, X, y,     **fit_params)
    409         else:
    410             # fit method of arity 2 (supervised transformation)
--> 411             return self.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)
    412 
    413 

//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn_pandas/__init__.pyc in fit(self, X, y)
    116         for columns, transformer in self.features:
    117             if transformer is not None:
--> 118                 transformer.fit(self._get_col_subset(X, columns))
    119         return self
    120 

TypeError: fit() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)`
```

What am I doing wrong? While the data in this case is all the same, I'm planning to work up a workflow for mixtures categorical, nominal and floating point features and sklearn_pandas seemed to be a logical fit.

Comment: After examining the code it seems the author forgot to handle `y` (`label`) values. [Look at the code](https://github.com/paulgb/sklearn-pandas/blob/master/sklearn_pandas/__init__.py): the `y` parameter is never used. I was also unable to reproduce the crossvalidation example in the documentation, but this might be due to versioning issues. Do you really need this? I found that pandas and sklearn integrate quite nicely.

Comment: To be honest, I wasn't sure if I needed it, but it looked as though it would be a useful wrapper and wanted to see if it could help. Appreciate the fact you took the time to go through the code. I wouldn't know where to start :)

Comment: `sklearn-pandas` author here. This is a tricky area because in sklearn `BaseEstimator` classes can have two different interfaces, one where `y` is passed and one where it is not. `sklearn-pandas` originally tried first with `y` in a `try/except` and if it threw a `TypeError` it tried again without `y`. To be honest I can't remember why that changed, but I must have thought it wasn't necessary.  
  
 I'm not sure if you've found a workaround but I've opened an issue to fix this when I have a chance, if you'd like to track it the issue is here: https://github.com/paulgb/sklearn-pandas/issues/12

Comment: Paul, that's great. I appreciate your time. I'm just starting out in sklearn and was trying to use the knowledge I've built up in pandas to  stretch myself a bit. While I know enough python to be dangerous, I'm usually out of my depth when something goes wrong. Just glad of the community on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Cross-posted with http://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/677/1156

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `sklearn_pandas` doesn't currently support estimators accepting an `y` vector with labels, you will have to use it only to transform all features to a Numpy matrix and then use the `KNeighborsClassifier` in a separate step.

**UPDATE 2015-08-10** - `sklearn_pandas` `DataFrameMapper` isn't intended to be used as a pipeline for transformation + model fitting, but only for transforming the columns selectively. If you want to transform then estimate a model, use a plain `sklearn` `Pipeline` with the dataframe mapper as first step.